# Writing Non Ascii Text on Python

Tags: python, encoding

Here simple script, I'm confused when to write non-ascii text. I want to write some character to a file, U know python write default is simple str. for instance, char number 128, the type is str, so I conclude that when writing that to a file, it doesn't matter because its type is str, not bytes. The write default is str too, not binary file

```
#python 3
#v.1

print(type(chr(128)))                    #The type is str

f = open('tep.txt','w')
f.write('\n')
for i in range(128,1000):
    f.write(chr(i))
f.close()
```

the code above is solved with this code

```
#v.2

f = open('tep.txt','wb')
f.write('\n'.encode('utf-8'))
for i in range(128,1000):
    f.write(chr(i).encode('utf-8'))
f.close()
```

I don't know what's happen with writing binary file.

Because char > 128 the type is str. So writing str to file with default should be ok, but it fails.

What's happening here?

Comment: What did you expecct to happen with this code and what happened instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3 strings are Unicode and must be encoded to a file.  The default encoding for `open` on some OSes is not UTF-8, so it is best to be explicit.  If you look at [open() documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), the default encoding on Windows is (on my system):

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.getpreferredencoding(False)
'cp1252'
>>> chr(128).encode('cp1252')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python38\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x80' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

That is probably the error you see (post it next time so we don't have to guess!).

It is best to be explicit about encoding whenever opening a file for reading and writing, since it varies by OS, and some encodings don't support every Unicode code point.

**Not Explicit** - Note the error complains about using CP1252 and not supporting that character:

```
>>> with open('tep.txt','w') as f: # NOT explicit
...   f.write(chr(128))
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Python38\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x80' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

**Explicit** - UTF-8 supports every valid Unicode code point:

```
>>> with open('tep.txt','w',encoding='utf8') as f:  # Explicit!
...   f.write(chr(128))
...
1
```

Further Reading:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer...Must Know About Unicode....](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html)